# Moved /var/lib/apt/lists, now packaging system doesn't work

Tags: apt

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in the morning and since than I'm struggling to do a simple update. I have troubles with apt-get. I have tried every solution i found out on the Internet, but didn't work. Here is the error i encounter when I try to

```
sudo apt-get update

E: Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-     updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages.IndexDiff - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

The whole thing started because when I tried to do the updates I received this error :"Requires installation of untrusted packages" and i found a link, I changed settings to accept source code and all other stuff and it still didn't work.

Then i went into another link and i did something like this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

and after that I had trouble with some keys and I found the solution, but now I have this error.

Comment: So you had no problems installing, and can use your computer normally, but this error crops up when you write `sudo apt-get update` in a console and write your password? Is this correct? Can you provide details as to what you've tried (links please!)

Answer (score 2):

If your Internet connection is stable, the repository may be having an issue.Try to change the download server to the best one by following these steps:

Ubuntu Software Center > Edit menu > Software Sources > 'Ubuntu Software' tab > Change 'Download from:' option to 'Other' > Click 'Select best server' and 'Choose server'

Next, close Software sources and Ubuntu Software Center and try updating...

Answer (score 2):

Since you've updated you question with extra info, the try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
   sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

and then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you still get issues, the try

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I didn't do this by myself I followed the steps from here [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661773) and about what you suggested I receive this: rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory

Comment: Ok that solved the problem with "sudo apt-get update" but now i have again this error "Requires installation of untrusted packages" what to do?

Comment: See the additional info in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should edit your question to include the information in your last comment (that you moved /var/lib/apt/lists around).

The file that it is not finding is now in `/var/lib/apt/lists.old`, instead of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` - so it cannot find it, and the error message is explaining exactly why.